# Interpreted and Compiled Language

Tags: java, python, programming-languages, theory

I have heard that python is an interpreted language, while java is a compiled language. This makes python (generally) easier to develop quickly, but makes it a bit slower than a compiled language. Java however is a bit harder to write quickly, but since it's compiled it runs faster.
So my question is, would it be possible to make a programming language that is interpreted for development, but then can be compiled for publishing? Does such a language exist already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, please try [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/)

It is a programming language that can be developed [incrementally](http://prl.ccs.neu.edu/blog/2016/08/02/tutorial-zero-to-sixty-in-racket/) and can be compiled into bytecode to run on a virtual machine, and has documents and [powerful macros](http://www.greghendershott.com/fear-of-macros/) that are [friendly to newcomers](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Eplragde/flaneries/TYR/index.html).

add:
you may want to read it:

https://www.pypy.org/

https://github.com/root-project/cling